# How to implement Wear OS notifications using flutter?

Tags: flutter, push-notification

I have been exploring implementations of flutter apps on the wear os but i am unable to find an example on how to implement any form of notifications.

Is it possible to directly use push notifications using existing flutter plugins (firebase) or is it still a work in progress?

I have also tried to find issues on github but there seems to be no mention of notifications for the wear os.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ware OS connects to your phone via Bluetooth. Notification on WareOS manages its application, this means that you just need to start any notification (local or push) on your phone and if it is connected to the smartwatch it will arrive automatically (unless you disable it from WareOS settings)

Local notifications must be managed [natively](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification), of course you can save yourself the trouble using a package (like [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)).

In case you want to use push notifications you will have to use Firebase